# Gson in Java : Attemped to deserialize a java.lang.Class. Forget to register a type adater

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to parse a JSON string like this one :

```
{
"Message":"OK",

"Obj":
  {
    "IdCatrgorie":"1",
    "Name":"catg1",
    "IdUser":"2"
  },

"Statue":"OK"
}
```

**Response Class (Android) :**

```
public class Response<T> {

    public String Message;
    public Class<T>  Obj;
    public String Statue;

public Response() {

    }
}
```

**Categorie Class :**

```
public class Categorie {



        public int IdCatrgorie;
        public int IdUser;
        public String Name;

        public Categorie(){}
}
```

**Main Class :**

```
private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int read;
        char[] chars = new char[1024];
        while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
            buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

        return buffer.toString();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
}


public static void Main(.....)
{
      String json;
        try {
            json = readUrl("http://192.168.56.1:91/truescan/");

            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

            Response<Categorie> posts = gson.fromJson(json, Response.class);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(response.Message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf("exception"+e.getMessage()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


}
```

But it throws me with

```
Attemped to deserialize a java.lang.Class. Forget to register a type adapter
```

***When i remove "Obj" attribute From Response classe it's work but witout get Obj Data***

Any ideas how should I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: According to the `Response` class, `Obj` needs to be `String`; however, in the json, it looks like an array.

Comment: did Obj Attribut must be a generic class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Response` class expects an String for `Obj` value; however, there is an object in the JSON. To solve this conflict, you can create a new class to contain `Obj` object, as given below:

```
public class Response {
    @SerializedName("Message")
    public String Message;

    @SerializedName("Obj")
    public Obj obj;

    @SerializedName("Statue")
    public String Statue;

}

public class Obj {
    @SerializedName("IdCatrgorie")
    int IdCatrgorie;

    @SerializedName("Name")
    String Name;

    @SerializedName("IdUser")
    int IdUser;
}
```

Or another approach might be putting all the content of `Obj` to a list of string:

```
public class Response {
    @SerializedName("Message")
    public String Message;

    @SerializedName("Obj")
    public Obj obj;

    @SerializedName("Statue")
    public String Statue;

}
```

**EDIT:**

In order to use generic classes with GSON, you should use `TypeToken`.

```
Type responseType = new TypeToken<Response<String>>() {}.getType();
Response<String> response = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, responseType);
```

Comment: Thank's @qamyoncu but Obj is generic Class, it's can be Many type of Classe, i changed my question

Comment: Thank's you helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

**i made a mistake ;**

**the Solution** :

```
public class Response<T> {

    public String Message;
    public T  Obj;
    public String Statue;

public Response() {

    }
}
```

in Main  class :

```
json = readUrl("http://192.168.56.1:91/truescan/");

            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

            Type responseType = new TypeToken<Response<Categorie>>() {}.getType();
            Response<Categorie> posts = gson.fromJson(json, responseType);
            Categorie catg = (Categorie)posts.Obj;

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(catg.Name), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```